# tooltip appears unaligned ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tooltip

since recently (for the last few days) I've noticed that the tooltip appear weirdly on youtube. But today I noticed that it's not only in YouTube but also in other places too such as GIMP, Clion, Lyx and more..

[image: the black tooltip]

idk what additional information is needed so if there's such info leave a massage and I will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and this one fixed it for me:
`sudo apt install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all`